# Express: getting ajax response from server

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, jquery-validate

I want to use ajax to send some form data to the server, have it checked and get a result back to the client. Currently, I am not receiving any data. I don't understand what I have to change to get this working.

**Server Side:**

In my Express `app.js`:

```
var login = require('./routes/login');
app.use('/login', login);
```

In my `login.js` route:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var loginObject = req.body;
    console.log(loginObject);
    var success = false; //This is just for testing!!
    if (success) {
        req.session.user = loginObject.email;
        req.session.userID = 1; //Stubbing
        res.render('home');
    } else {
        res.json({'success': false});
    }
});
```

**Client side:**

In my `index.jade` file:

```
script(src='/javascripts/login_window.js')
```

In my `login_window.js` file (using the jQuery Validation plugin):

```
$('#loginForm').validate({
    rules: {
        modalMail: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        modalPass: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        element.closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
    },
    success: function(label, element) {
        $(element).closest('div.form-group').addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/login',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: form,
            contentType: 'application/json',

            complete: function() {
                console.log('process complete');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log('process success');
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('process error');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

When I try this, I get absolutely nothing in the console window. What can I do?

This is what I get:

[image: console]

Comment: see network tab in browswe, request is sent or not?

Comment: GET request for the page has status 304 (so not changed) and POST request has status 200 (OK). The data is received on the server, because I can display it there.

Comment: and whats the responce for POST request?

Comment: I get nothing. In the `$.ajax` call, I do `console.log` on complete, on success and on error, but there is nothing.

Comment: see my answer, i tnink your view is re rendering, try doing a true success from login route

Comment: thats working, you are getting success : false thats what we are sending

Comment: your problem is solved now yo are getting the respnce via ajax

Comment: But how can I render a page (say index) and use the ajax response to add a button or something like that?

Comment: Also, when using `console.log` it should be in the console and not in the HTML page. Right? I don't understand why it's in the HTML page? The `console.log` should print 'process complete', 'process success' or 'process error'..

Comment: again rendering a view will give no benefit of ajax request, and you are still using a form to have a ajax response

Comment: How can I do it then, when somebody tries to log in and their credentials are wrong? I want to display an alert when the ajax request returns false. This page appears after form submit.

Comment: can you tell me that when this page appears having this object? after form submit or initial page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is okay. and i thing you have set success to false so it is not sending back data it is re rendering the same view so nothing on console

The line that is working is

```
        res.render('index', {login: false});
```

To test

change

```
  var success = true;
```

Secondly, instead of rendering a view you can send a json data or some thing on ajax request

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
    var loginObject = req.body;
    console.log(loginObject);
    var success = false; //This is just for testing!!
    if (success) {
        req.session.user = loginObject.email;
        req.session.userID = 1; //Stubbing
        res.json({"success":true});
    } else {
        res.json({"success":false});
    }
});
```

Comment: When I set `success` to `true`, it just goes to my `home` page. I put it to `false` in order to test the ajax response.

Comment: okay than in else block send this res.json({"success":false});

Comment: and see your console after doing this

Comment: But when I just send json using `res.json`, it prints the JSON in a blank HTML page and there is still nothing in the console.

Comment: have you removed  res.render('index', {login: false}); ?

Comment: else block be like else {
        res.json({"success":false});
    }

Comment: Yes, I have. I would like to render some page (say index) and catch the ajax response in the javascript and when it says 'false', a popup has to be shown or something like that. It still shows a blank HTML page with the JSON in it.

Comment: i think after returning res.json() you will be having something in console recheck. it quite imposible that you dont have now

Comment: I'll add an image of the page I get and the console.

Comment: I really don't understand, I've compared to many other stackoverflow questions and I have exactly the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here, otherwise, this is another problem...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: form, // <--
        ...
```

The plugin's `form` argument simply represents the plugin's form object.

You would need a jQuery selector and to use something like `.serialize()` to get the actual data...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        ...
```